# How do I suppress messages in the echo area (e.g. `Fill column set to 80 (was 80)`)?

Tags: python, echo-area, message, fill-column, inhibit-message

When I open a Python file I keep seeing `Fill column set to 80 (was 80)` message in the echo area. I know I have set it this limit , but I don't want to be keep reminded about it.

Is it possible to suppress this message?

my setup:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
    (setq python-indent 4)
    (set-fill-column 80)
    (setq tab-width 4)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@NickD answered the question well. But you can also do this, just to inhibit showing messages for `set-fill-column`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode  nil
                  python-indent     4
                  tab-width         4)
            (let ((inhibit-message  t))
              (set-fill-column 80))))
```

Or this:

```lisp
(defun my-set-fill-column (arg)
  (let ((inhibit-message  t))
    (set-fill-column arg)))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode  nil
                  python-indent     4
                  tab-width         4)
            (my-set-fill-column 80)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the `inhibit-message` reminder!

Comment: I keep having following debug error not sure what is wrong on my end: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/c18994af8640daa68943c0e7d5c59ae0 . I can add this to my question if its required. Should I combine it with @NickD's function ?

Comment: I think there was a typo in the `my-set-fill-column` function  which I fixed. Can you try now?

Comment: @NickD I have also changed `set-fill-column ` to   `my-set-fill-column`; the error is fixed, thank you.

Comment: Code examples 1 and 3 seem to be the same and should probably only reference `set-fill-column` not `my-set-fill-column`

Comment: Corrected typos etc. The point is just to `inhibit-message` around a call to `set-fill-column`.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the specific example case...

`set-fill-column` is a command which is *only* intended to be used interactively.

To set the fill column programmatically, just do this:

`(setq fill-column 80)`

Which is exactly what `set-fill-column` would do, after validating that `80` was a valid argument and displaying the message -- but you don't need anything to validate `80` as a fill column, and you don't want the message.

Comment: Could I also do `(setq-default fill-column 80)`

Comment: You can; or alternatively use `M-x customize-option` which will likewise set the default.

Comment: To be safe I did the both :-)

Comment: If you do both then you'll probably forget that later if you ever try to change it, and potentially wind up confused that things aren't working.  Just use one approach or the other.